# Help in proving $\text{Bdry}(A)= \overline{A} \setminus \text{Int}(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would like to proof the following; $\text{Bdry}(A)= \overline{A} \setminus \text{Int}(A)$.So here is my attempt.

Proof:

($\supseteq$) Suppose that $z \in \overline{A} \setminus \text{Int}(A)$, then we get that $z \in \overline{A}$ and $z \notin \text{Int}(A)$, then for all $r >0$ we have that $B(z;r) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and since $z \notin \text{Int}(A)$ there doesn't exist any open ball centered at $z$
such that $B(z;r) \subseteq A$, which means that for all $r >0$ we get that $B(z;r) \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$, so $z \in \text{Bdry}(A)$.

$(\subseteq)$ I've got problems in this one. Suppose $z \in \text{Bdry}(A)$ then for all $r>0$: $B(z;r) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and $B(z;r) \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$, this means that there isn't any open ball centered at $z$ such that $B(z;r) \subseteq A$, but from here I can't see a way to conclude, any clue for this reverse containment would be appreciated.

Comment: for all $r>0$ $B(z;r) \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$ means that there isn't any open ball centered at $z$ such that $B(z;r) \subseteq \color{red}A$.

Comment: Oops, I did the correction already

Comment: So you are done, aren't you?

Comment: Oh, then the point isn't in the interior, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general topology; a point x is in boundary iff it is neither in interior nor in exterior of the set. For your case  you can adapt this for metric space
$$
\begin{array}{lllr}
 x\ \in Bdry(A) & \Leftrightarrow  & x\notin \overset{ \  \circ}{A} \  \wedge \  x \notin (X-A)^\circ & 
   \\ 
 & \Leftrightarrow  & x\notin \overset{ \  \circ}{A} \  \wedge \  x \notin (X-  \overset{ \  -}{A})  & \ \ \ ...\left( (X-A)^\circ =X-  \overset{ \  -}{A} \right)  
 \\ 
 & \Leftrightarrow  &  x\notin \overset{ \  \circ}{A} \  \wedge \  x \in \overset{ \  -}{A}& 
  \\ 
 & \Leftrightarrow  & x\in  \overset{ \  -}{A}- \overset{ \ \circ}{A} & 
\end{array}%
$$